# How do I round an edge of a rectangle?

Tags: modeling, mesh

I've been wondering how to do this for a while but I couldn't find anything that gave me answers. I'm trying to make a realistic-ish model but I don't know how to round the edges.

Comment: Hello :). Is the *Bevel Modifier* what you're looking for? Perhaps add an image to illustrate.

Comment: It might be. I'm not sure how to add an image though.

Comment: [How to add images to a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/317576/652639) should help :).

Comment: Yes! Thank you alot!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Bevel tool.

1. In Edit mode, select all the edges you want to be rounded.
2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> to initiate the tool.
3. Adjust the offset (*radius*) of the rounded corners by sliding your mouse.
4. Adjust the number of segments (*subdivisions*) you want with the mouse wheel. The more there is, the smoother the corner will be.
5. Validate the operation with a mouse click or by pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

You can adjust those parameters, and many others, by expanding the "Last Operator" panel (bottom left of the Viewport; it should be labelled "Bevel"):

[image]

I assume you want to round edges of a *rectangle*, a planar surface; if you want to round the edges of a volume, you should use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> instead.